# How to set up apache on LAN (MAMP)

Tags: apache-2.2, local-area-network

I have 2 computers on a LAN (OS X and Vista).  MAMP installed on OS X.  I want view the site being developed from my Vista machine.  I shared the htdocs file on the LAN.  Clearly only the html is working properly.

What do I need to change to make Apache host my site on the LAN?

**Solution:** Such a dumb mistake: I was typing `\\192.168.x.x` (fill in x) which is the shared file.  This does not share the server.  `http://192.168.x.x` is the correct address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is pretty good [documentation](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/first-steps)

I suspect you just need to put your HTML files into the correct `htdocs` folder, start Apache, and then, on your Vista PC, point a web browser at the name or IP-address of your Mac. For example, `http://192.168.1.23:8888/` (I believe MAMP is set to use port 8888 by default)

---

(Edit)

Using `\\` as a prefix makes the web-browser use the `File:` protocol not the `http:` protocol.

It is only if you use the http protocol that the request is sent to Apache (The A in MAMP). It is only by sending the request to Apache that you get Apache to **run** the PHP code as a program and send the **output** of that PHP program to the web-browser.

Putting `\\` in front means the request goes to a File server, not to Apache. The file server doesn't attempt to run the PHP code, it just send the PHP source code (and not the results of running that code).